# Bootstrap tabs does not seem to be switching between different tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have made a simple tabs but now I have faced this problem that this tab does not seem to be switching between different tabs name. Here is the link where you can see and customize my tab:
http://jsfiddle.net/6gahxfjn/

```
<div class="tabs">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#namayandegi" aria-controls="namayandegi" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">نمایندگی هاست لینوکس</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#files" aria-controls="files" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">میزبانی فایل نامحدود</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#serverspecial" aria-controls="serverspecial" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">سرور اختصاصی ویژه</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#servergreen" aria-controls="servergreen" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">سرور اختصاصی سبز</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#server" aria-controls="server" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">سرورمجازی</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#linuxspecial" aria-controls="linuxspecial" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">هاست لینوکس ویژه</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#linux" aria-controls="linux" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">هاست لینوکس</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
                                <h3 style="padding-top:100px;">هاست لینوکس</h3>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                                        <img class="img-left" src="assets/img/linux-host.png"></img>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                                        <p class="paragra">
                                        سرویس هاست لینوکس معمولی جهت ارائه خدمات به وب سایت هایی با بازدید و مصرف معمولی از منابع سرور است که کدنویسی و برنامه نویسی آن بر پایه سیستم عامل لینوکس و با زبان های برنامه نویسی php یا CGI یا پرل و ... می باشد. البته هاست لینوکس بدین معناست که فقط سیستم عامل نصب شده، روی سرور لینوکس است و هیچ ارتباطی با سیستم عامل کامپیوتر شخصی شما ندارد و چنانچه روی کامپیوتر شما ویندوز نصب باشد به راحتی می توانید از هاست لینوکس استفاده کنید. سرورهای این نوع سرویس، همگی در بستر شبکه ای دیتاسنتر هاست ایران در داخل ایران میزبانی می شوند و از کنترل پنل cpanel در ایران استفاده می کند و وب سرور آن آپاچی می باشد.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <a href="#"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="namayandegi">...</div>
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="files">...</div>
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="serverspecial">...</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

So how can I fix this p

Comment: I'm pretty much newbie here, so please instead of giving me negative points, reply my question, thx!

Comment: You need to add javascript to support layout...

Comment: Please add pictures of what you mean exactly, the link might break sometime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution http://jsfiddle.net/6gahxfjn/1/

```js
$('.nav a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#namayandegi" aria-controls="namayandegi" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">نمایندگی هاست لینوکس</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#files" aria-controls="files" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">میزبانی فایل نامحدود</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#serverspecial" aria-controls="serverspecial" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">سرور اختصاصی ویژه</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#servergreen" aria-controls="servergreen" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">سرور اختصاصی سبز</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#server" aria-controls="server" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">سرورمجازی</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#linuxspecial" aria-controls="linuxspecial" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">هاست لینوکس ویژه</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#linux" aria-controls="linux" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">هاست لینوکس</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="linuxspecial">
      <h3 style="padding-top:100px;">هاست لینوکس</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <img class="img-left" src="assets/img/linux-host.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
          <p class="paragra">
            سرویس هاست لینوکس معمولی جهت ارائه خدمات به وب سایت هایی با بازدید و مصرف معمولی از منابع سرور است که کدنویسی و برنامه نویسی آن بر پایه سیستم عامل لینوکس و با زبان های برنامه نویسی php یا CGI یا پرل و ... می باشد. البته هاست لینوکس بدین معناست که فقط سیستم عامل نصب شده، روی سرور لینوکس است و هیچ ارتباطی با سیستم عامل کامپیوتر شخصی شما ندارد و چنانچه روی کامپیوتر شما ویندوز نصب باشد به راحتی می توانید از هاست لینوکس استفاده کنید. سرورهای این نوع سرویس، همگی در بستر شبکه ای دیتاسنتر هاست ایران در داخل ایران میزبانی می شوند و از کنترل پنل cpanel در ایران استفاده می کند و وب سرور آن آپاچی می باشد.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="namayandegi">Namayandegi</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="files">Files</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="serverspecial">Server Special</div>
     <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="servergreen">Server Green</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="linux">Linux</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="server">Server</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You are missing **bootstrap** and **jQuery** `JavaScript` library files.